# Disable dates using factory response UI Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable a date in the UI Bootstrap Datepicker connected to a Google calendar if that dates already have 3 or more events.

Thus far I get the array of events using an Angular Factory like this:

```
gardenpage.factory('Dates', function($http, $q) {
var deffered = $q.defer();
var data = [];  
var Dates = {};

Dates.async = function() {
   $http.get('http://localhost:7777/events')
   .success(function (d) {
   data = d;
   deffered.resolve();
});
return deffered.promise;
};
Dates.data = function() { return data; };

return Dates;
});
```

The list of dates needs a bit more preprocessing so I have a function that puts the only dates that have 3 or more entries in a scope-variable:

```
$scope.occurences = ['2014-07-21','2014-07-28'];
```

Now finally this is my modified default UI Bootstrap date picker date disable function:

```
// Disable weekend selection
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {

return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 || 
$scope.date_occurences.indexOf( $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ) !== -1 ));
};
```

It works as expected except for one little quirk, when the "disabled" function is called by the date picker, the array is empty, waiting for the async callback I presume. Which is why it's first as I select a date in the date picker as my dates gets disabled.

So how to get the callback before the date picker disable function is called, or how do I make it wait ? One alternative might be to refresh the Datepicker after the callback has arrived, but I'm not sure if that function exists on the date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't solve this exactly as stated above but a bit of a workaround:

1.
Used a small code that I found in a stack overflow comment http://plnkr.co/edit/Xwq7YtAD6qNHQw1aES3H?p=preview . Which lets you call the Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker "refreshView" using a button or other type of action. Basically setting up a new directive

```
`app.directive('jmDpRefreshView',function() {
   var noop = function(){};
   var refreshDpOnNotify = function (dpCtrl) {
     return function() {
       dpCtrl.refreshView();
     };
   };
return {
  require: 'datepicker',
  link: function(scope,elem,attrs,dpCtrl) {
    var refreshPromise = scope[attrs.jmDpRefreshView];
    refreshPromise.then(noop,noop,refreshDpOnNotify(dpCtrl));
   } 
 };
```

});`

To call the refreshView functionality

`$scope.toggleDisableMode = function() {
    dateDisableDeferred.notify(new Date().getTime());
  };`

The function toggleDisableMode can be called using any type of action, for instance using a button to disable dates from the server: "ng-click='toggleDisableMode()'"

Another thing that might help you is either you could preload your Dates from the server

```
//preload
$scope.dates = disable_dates();

function disable_dates() {
    console.log("disable dates function")
    Dates.async().then(function() {
        $scope.data = Dates.data();
        //do whatever you like with your data
    });
}
```

Or you could call the ".notify()" for the deferred when the data has been fetched from the server and it will disable when it is done.

```
    function disable_dates() {
    console.log("disable dates function")
    Dates.async().then(function() {
        $scope.data = Dates.data();
        //console.log($scope.data )
        //do whatever you like with your server data.

        //notice this line, calls the disable function
        dateDisableDeferred.notify(new Date().getTime());
    });
}
```

This solution is attributed to this question and the comments in there:
[angular ui datepicker refresh disabled dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840819/angular-ui-datepicker-refresh-disabled-dates)